# Adding a field to a model using a foreign key in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have a table called `family` that has a key called `survey_id` that is a foreign key to the `survey` table.  Is there a way to return a `survey` model with data from the `family` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify association in Family model
`belongs_to :survey`. Then you can retrieve associated model `instance_of_family_model.survey`
Recommend reading this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `survey` association on `Family` model

```rb
class Family < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

And than you can get `survey` on any instance of `Family` model

```rb
@family = Family.find(1)
@family.survey
```